# Retrieving Image from Firebase to placing it into a pdf by appending src url to image tag

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-storage, html2pdf

I have been getting a problem, the problem is like i can't place image into the pdf output generated by html2pdf().

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("cvggnbtn")
    .addEventListener("click", () => {
            const invoice = this.document.getElementById("cv-template");
            console.log(invoice);
            console.log(window);
            document.getElementById("photo2").src=imageUrl;
            var opt = {
                margin: -1,
                filename:'myfile.pdf',
                image: { type: 'pdf', quality: 1},
                html2canvas: { scale: 1 },
                jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' }
            };
          
            html2pdf().set({
                pagebreak: { mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy'] }
              });
            html2pdf().from(invoice).save();
        })
 }
function geturlfromdatabase(URL)
{
  const realdb = firebase.database();
   const dbref = realdb.ref();
   const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   if (!user) {
     console.log("User is not signed in");
     return;
   }
  
   const userId = user.uid;
   const imageUrlRef = firebase.database().ref(`users/${userId}/template1/Personal-data/ImagesLinks`);
   
   imageUrlRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      imageUrl = snapshot.val();
     console.log(imageUrl);
     
     if (snapshot.exists()&&imageUrl) {
       userimg.src = imageUrl;
       userimg.style.display = "block";
       selectbtn.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("photo2").src=imageUrl;
     }
     else{
      console.log("user not uploaded image");
     }
   }).catch((error) => {
     console.error(error);
   });
}
```

like image is not displayed into pdf, it leaves some space there for image, the image url is being attached to photo2.src.

Html File :

```
<div class="container" id="cv-template">
              <div class="row1  " id="cv-template" >
                <div class=" text-center background  " id="first" >
                  <img src="./NFT.png" class="img-fluid  mt-4"  id="photo2">
                  <div class="container" id="presnol-info">
                  
                    
                    <h1 id="FirstnameT">Himanshu </h1>
                      <h1 id="LastnameT"></h1>
                    <p id="ProfessionT">Profession</p>
                    <h4 id="contactT">Contact   </h4>
                    <p id="addressT"> <b>Addess</b> </p>
                    <!-- <p id="addressTinfo2"></p>
                    <p id="CountryT"></p>
                    <p id="CityT"></p> -->
                    <p id="pincodeT"></p>
                    <p id="PhoneT"> <b>Phone</b> </p>
                    <p id="PhoneNumberT"></p>
                    <p id="EmailT"> <b>E-mail</b> </p>
                    <p id="EmailidT"></p>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
```

I tried various things like made a preview button and checked whether image was visible or not. image was being visible at that time. but after converting it to pdf image is not shown inside the pdf.